# echo text with preceding spaces but without new line

Tags: windows, batch-file, newline

If I use `<nul set/p=    some text` or `set/p "=    some text"<nul`, preceding spaces are removed, even if I use character with `0xFF` code. How can I echo specified number of spaces at the beginning of the line w/o trailing CR/LF?

Comment: The aim is also speed of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) If text is echoed on a new line, then just add backspace char in front of the output text.
`<nul set/p=[BS char here directly, without brackets]     some text`
In ANSI and ASCII codetables it has code `0x08`.
b) If the text needed to be placed as continuation of already existed line, then additionally add one non-space char before BS char, for example "Middle Dot" (`0xFA`).
`<nul set/p=[MD char (0xFA), then BS char (0x08)]     some text`
Works fine in WinXP and Win7.

Comment: And are there some guru, who knows the answer, applicable for DOS?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a backspace character works well at the start of the line.

```
@echo off
:: define BS as a BackSpace character
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H&for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%A"
set /p "=%bs%     some text"<nul
pause
```

Comment: May be exist shorter way? Second `for` looks excessively.

Comment: @green You only have to execute the first line once, to generate the environment variable.  You can find other methods, but they will be slower and involve external commands.

Comment: I know about once-use of that line, but I wonder, is it really only `for` generates empty output?

Comment: @green The for command is generating an invisible control character.  You can enter a backspace into the script with an editor that is able to embed control characters, if it will never be stripped by a different text editor in the future.

Comment: In previous my comment, I meant question: "Just only `for` command generates empty output (with command prompt involving), or some other commands with similar effect also may be used?".

Comment: @green  Where do you see `for` that generates empty output?

Comment: `for %%B in (1) do rem` Isn't it?

Comment: @green That compound statement generates a backspace character and is the usual quick way to do it when using internal commands.  It's a non-documented technique, like very many batch file tricks are.

Comment: May be I had spoken incorrect about "empty output". More clearly will be the following: I wonder, how the char from prompt string can "travel" to stdout, and which commands, besides `for`, doing the same (help with such "travelling"). Which chars can travel in such manner also?